# Intellij - Command Line run to Configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command

I'm working on a java project and have a working command line call to start the program, but I'm struggling to figure out how to call this from Intellij. I can call this in my command line in terminal and see the expected output.

`$ ./normalize --manifest /MyUsrPath/myFile.csv --input /MyUsrPath/myOtherFile.csv`

[image]

However - I'm receiving the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class .normalize`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[BashSupport](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport) plug-in provides run configurations for the shell scripts. You can also use [External Tools feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html) and [this plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9744-run-configuration-for-external-tools).